# Loopy Belief Propagation

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, sparse-arrays

I look for an efficient way to implement a [Belief Propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief_propagation) in [Pairwise Markov Random Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_random_field).

Each node is a binary random variable, and the unary potential function  is

```
nodePotential[v_] := Piecewise[{{a, v == 1}, {1-a, v == -1}}]
```

The pairwise potential function is

```
pairwisePotential[p_] := {{p, 1 - p}, {1 - p, p}}
```

I have a data structure which contains the unary potential of each node:

```
nodePot=Association@Map[# -> {0.3, 0.7} &, VertexList@g1]
```

And data structure which contains the pairwise potential is a matrix

```
edgeSimilarity=AdjacencyMatrix[g1]*0.6;
```

Note that I deal with different unary/pairwise potential, but for simplifying the question, I am using here homogeneous.

With the following function, I calculate the LBP

```
LBP[data_, index_] := 
 Module[{totalPo, nonZeroPosition, nonZeroValues, nzp, nzv, newP, edP, spNZV},
  totalPo = Total@data["NonzeroValues"];
  nonZeroPosition = data["NonzeroPositions"];
  nonZeroValues = data["NonzeroValues"];
  newP = Thread[List[Flatten[nonZeroPosition], index]];
  edP = edgeSimilarity[[index]]["NonzeroValues"];
  edP = DeleteCases[edP, 0.0];
  edP = pairwisePotential[#] & /@ edP;
  edP = (Exp[totalPo - #] & /@ nonZeroValues)*edP;
  nzv = (nodePot[index].#) & /@ Flatten[edP, 1];
  {newP, nzv}
  ]
```

I work in log domain to prevent the numerical issues in dense graph

```
newMessageMatrix[data_] := Module[{res, positions, values},
  res = Transpose@data;
  positions = Flatten[Join [{{{{1, 1}}}}, Transpose[{res[[1]], res[[1]]}]], 2];
  values = Log[Flatten@Join[{1.0000000000001}, res[[2]]]];
   Chop@With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]}, 
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
     SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> List}], 
     SparseArray[positions -> values, Dimensions[s], 0], 
     SetSystemOptions[spopt]]]
    ]

s = AdjacencyMatrix@g1;
sT = 2*s;
```

Each iteration of LBP is

```
valuesAndPositions = LBP[sT[[#]], #] & /@VertexList[g1];
resMat = newMessageMatrix[valuesAndPositions];
```

Any suggestion how on speed up the calculation and reduce memory use